# I am getting JMeter Out of Memory error even after I already upgraded my RAM from 8G to 16G

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

Can someone please help me with the *Out of Memory* (OOM) error that I encountered while running **JMeter**

I am a newbie in **Java** and in JMeter, and also in performance testing. I used the command prompt but I am still encountering *Out of Memory* issue. I tried to adjust the heap size but running did not continue every time I change it.

My current heap size is below

```
    set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

I added another memory: from **8GB**, my memory is now **16GB**.
But when I run it again with **1000 threads**, the error below is shown:

```
Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-130,5,main]. See the log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-63,5,main]. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-135,5,main]. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-19,5,main]. See log file for details.
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 32756 bytes for ChunkPool::allocate
```

Sometimes I am also encountering just this error:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 32756 bytes for ChunkPool::allocate
```

Can someone please help me. I am just a beginner so I would appreciate if you will reply with terms that are not too technical.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting indicates that underlying [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) is not able to create a new native thread / process.

1. Try increasing limits for the operating system, i.e. if you're on [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) you can check the maximum number of threads using [`ulimit -n` command](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)
2. In any case you can decrease the stack size via [`-Xss JVM argument`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.71.doc/diag/appendixes/cmdline/Xss.html)

Unfortunately in its current shape your question doesn't provide enough information in order to come up with a comprehensive answer, if above hints don't help consider adding more details like:

- Operating system version and architecture
- JMeter version
- Java version and archivecture
- At least first 20 lines of the [.HPROF file](https://docwiki.cisco.com/docwiki-eol.html)

Also make sure to follow recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article

Answer (score 0):

the flag Xmx indicates the maximum memory for the JVM.  You should increase your xmx value to something more appropriate for your usage.

try:

set HEAP=-Xms1g **-Xmx4g** -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m

Comment: Hi,Everytime i change the heap size, there comes an error. My current RAM is 16G but when the heap size to 8G or 4G:


Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
errorlevel=1


When I change to 2G:


Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
errorlevel=1

Answer (score 0):

change Heap size in jmeter.sh file if you are using Linux/ubuntu, Jmeter.bat in windows. Increase the `-Xmx1g =`*to half of the memory of the system* i.e., 4gb(-Xmx4g). also try to increase the user load from 500 and check the CPU and RAM utilization in Task Manager of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the out of memory issue on trying to run 10k vusers in 8GB RAM. Later on increased the instance memory as 16GB and 10k vusers load ran successfully.

1. Increase JVM memory as 12 GB in */etc/profile/*
2. Increase JMeter Heap as 10GB in "*jmeter*" file(Linux OS). ('set HEAP' option is available in "*jmeter.bat*" file for Windows server)

3.Open files limit - 65535

4. maximum user process limit - 65535

---

Open the command window as root user
Execute following commands and update values to change the default limit

1. *vim /etc/security/limits.conf*

*root soft     nproc          65535*
*root hard     nproc          65535*
*root soft     nofile         65535*
*root hard     nofile         65535*

2. *vim /etc/sysctl.conf*

*fs.file-max = 65535*

*sysctl -p*

3. *reboot*

After rebooting, the changes will be affected in the machine and kindly cross verify that.

**Should run the JMeter script in Non-GUI as a root user only.**

**Note**: Delete dump heap file in "bin" if any.